# React-Admin How to change the "Dashboard" name in the menu

Tags: dashboard, react-admin

How can I change the "dashoboard" menu name in the react-admin?

By default it's name is always "Dashboard" even in the [Demo](https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/) [image]

the name is Dashboard. Someone knows a way to change the name or if it is even possible to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the **Menu.tsx**, don't call it like

```
<DashboardMenuItem onClick={onMenuClick} sidebarIsOpen={open} />
```

Instead call it like a normal menu item but pointing to the dashboard component

```
<MenuItemLink
        to={`/`} // by default react-admin renders Dashboard on this route
        primaryText="Your Text"
        leftIcon={<YourIcon />}
        onClick={onMenuClick}
        sidebarIsOpen={open}
        dense={dense}
      />
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, it helped me to find what I realy needed.

Comment: @JohnBarbosa what did you end up doing, I am interested in the same problem

Comment: @drKreso I have done this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59880647/11825998

Answer (score 2):

Like in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59879156/react-admin-how-to-change-the-dashboard-name-in-the-menu/59879688#59879688) is showed that in the **MenuItemLink** has an atribute called **primaryText="Your Text"** that you can use in your own

```
<DashboardMenuItem onClick={onMenuClick} classes={classes} primaryText="Your Text" />
```

To change the name of the default "Dashboard" name for what you want.

Comment: My question is how do I change Menu.tsx, since this is in ra-ui-materialui package. Do I need to fork it or what? Looks like overkill to me.

Comment: I think this should be accepted answer. the RaMenu.DashboardItem extends mui item link, so we can use primaryText property without adding anything else (onlick handler or classes)

Answer (score 1):

So more detailed answer is:

1. Override layout

```js
// in src/Admin.js
  <Admin
        layout={MyLayout}
        title="SuperCoolProject"
        theme={myTheme}
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
        authProvider={authProvider}
      >
```

2. Use custom menu in layout. (it's not sidebar)

```js
// in src/MyLayout.js
import React from "react";
import { Layout } from "react-admin";
import MyMenu from "./MyMenu";

const MyLayout = (props) => <Layout {...props} menu={MyMenu} />;

export default MyLayout;
```

3. Change menu so it still renders resources and add custom MenuItemLinks you need (vs. one hardcoded "dashboard")

```js
// in src/Menu.js
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useMediaQuery } from "@material-ui/core";
import { MenuItemLink, getResources } from "react-admin";
import DefaultIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ViewList";
import SettingsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Settings";
import HomeIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Home";
import HelpIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Help";

const Menu = ({ onMenuClick, logout }) => {
  const isXSmall = useMediaQuery((theme) => theme.breakpoints.down("xs"));
  const open = useSelector((state) => state.admin.ui.sidebarOpen);
  const resources = useSelector(getResources);
  return (
    <div>
      <MenuItemLink
        to="/home"
        primaryText="Home"
        leftIcon={<HomeIcon />}
        onClick={onMenuClick}
        sidebarIsOpen={open}
      />
      {resources.map((resource) => (
        <MenuItemLink
          key={resource.name}
          to={`/${resource.name}`}
          primaryText={
            (resource.options && resource.options.label) || resource.name
          }
          leftIcon={resource.icon ? <resource.icon /> : <DefaultIcon />}
          onClick={onMenuClick}
          sidebarIsOpen={open}
        />
      ))}
      <MenuItemLink
        to="/custom-route"
        primaryText="Settings"
        leftIcon={<SettingsIcon />}
        onClick={onMenuClick}
        sidebarIsOpen={open}
      />
      <MenuItemLink
        to="/help-center"
        primaryText="Help Center"
        leftIcon={<HelpIcon />}
        onClick={onMenuClick}
        sidebarIsOpen={open}
      />
      {isXSmall && logout}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

[image]

Comment: yes, that's it. there is more than one way to solve the same problem